# W3C Validation error XHTML markup- end tag for "div" omitted

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, w3c

validated web page using the W3C markup validation service found at:

http://validator.w3.org/

The error and info returned are:

**Error** Line 112, Column 7: end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

```
 </body>
```

**Info** Line 16, Column 1: start tag was here

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

I cannot see an error in my markup however, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your nav div is missing a closing div. There's a starting div at start nav, but no closing div by the close nav comment. Your source code has one more opening div than closoing div and that looks like the missing one.